# Бегущая строка в абзаце

Tags: c#

Помогите встроить бегущую строку в этот вот абзац.

Здесь по умолчанию текст меняется просто, но мне нужно, чтобы он был бегущей строкой:

```
{ "MessageBox", new PanelConfig
    {
        Available = true,
        Dock = "TopRightDock",
        Order = 7,
        AnchorX = "Right",
        AnchorY = "Bottom",
        Margin = "0 0 0 0.005",
        Width = 1f,
        Height = 0.95f,
        BackgroundColor = "0 0 0 0.4",
        Text = new PanelTextConfig
        {
            Align = TextAnchor.MiddleCenter,
            FontColor = DefaultFontColor,
            FontSize = 14,
        },
        PanelSettings = new Dictionary<string,object>
        {
            { "MessageUpdateFrequency (seconds)", MessageUpdateFrequency },
            { "MsgOrder","normal" }
        }
    }
}`
```

Comment: WinForms? WPF? UWP? или что-то еще поверх них типа DevExpress? Рискну предположить по коду что это WinForms + DevExpress. Добавьте необходимые метки и **минимальный самодостаточный воспроизводимый пример кода** http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, что в этом тебе поможет `Timer`. На каждое срабатывание таймера вешаешь обработчик события, который и будет двигать твою строку.

Comment: Можно по подробнее, я плохо разбираюсь в программировании.